# Groovy & Java MongoDB Driver bulk insertion throws exception

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy

the following groovy scripts use the Java MongoDB Driver and try to run a bulk insertion in a separate thread by using GPars.
The first script [mongobulk1.groovy](https://github.com/schneidermatic/mongo-meter/blob/master/groovy/mongobulk1.groovy) works fine but it runs without the 'BulkWriteOperation'.

For a better performance the second script [mongobulk2.groovy](https://github.com/schneidermatic/mongo-meter/blob/master/groovy/mongobulk2.groovy) is using the 'BulkWritOperation' feature but it throws the following exception:

```
Caught: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no operations
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no operations
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:504)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.reportResult(ForkJoinTask.java:567)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:611)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.invoke(ForkJoinPool.java:1492)
    at groovyx.gpars.extra166y.ParallelArrayWithMapping.apply(ParallelArrayWithMapping.java:48)
    at groovyx.gpars.extra166y.ParallelArray.apply(ParallelArray.java:329)
    at groovyx.gpars.pa.GParsPoolUtilHelper.eachParallelPA(GParsPoolUtilHelper.groovy:192)
    at groovyx.gpars.GParsPoolUtil.eachParallel(GParsPoolUtil.java:358)
    at Importer$_main_closure1.doCall(mongobulk2.groovy:107)
    at groovyx.gpars.GParsPool$_withExistingPool_closure1.doCall(GParsPool.groovy:174)
    at groovyx.gpars.GParsPool$_withExistingPool_closure1.doCall(GParsPool.groovy)
    at groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withExistingPool(GParsPool.groovy:173)
    at groovyx.gpars.GParsPool$withExistingPool$2.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool(GParsPool.groovy:145)
    at groovyx.gpars.GParsPool$withPool$1.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool(GParsPool.groovy:121)
    at groovyx.gpars.GParsPool$withPool$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool(GParsPool.groovy:100)
    at groovyx.gpars.GParsPool$withPool.call(Unknown Source)
    at Importer.main(mongobulk2.groovy:106)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no operations
    at org.bson.util.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:36)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.executeBulkWriteOperation(DBCollectionImpl.java:132)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeBulkWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:1663)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeBulkWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:1659)
    at com.mongodb.BulkWriteOperation.execute(BulkWriteOperation.java:90)
    at Importer.run(mongobulk2.groovy:82)
    at Importer$run$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at Importer$_main_closure1_closure2.doCall(mongobulk2.groovy:112)
    at groovyx.gpars.pa.GParsPoolUtilHelper$_eachParallelPA_closure8.doCall(GParsPoolUtilHelper.groovy:192)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.op(Unknown Source)
    at groovyx.gpars.extra166y.AbstractParallelAnyArray$OUPap.leafApply(AbstractParallelAnyArray.java:640)
    at groovyx.gpars.extra166y.PAS$FJOApply.atLeaf(PAS.java:147)
    at groovyx.gpars.extra166y.PAS$FJBase.compute(PAS.java:108)
    at jsr166y.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:148)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:305)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.execTask(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:575)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:755)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.work(ForkJoinPool.java:617)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:369)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, your algo is wrong and you trigger `builder.execute()` at a time when your builder has no request to make (i.e. 'no operation').

You can check this by adding a sysout before the `builder.execute()`:

```
println "nb request to execute: $builder.requests.size"
BulkWriteResult result = builder.execute()
```

Here is the associated mongo client source code:

```
Assertions.isTrue("no operations", !writeRequests.isEmpty());
```

Comment: Thanx! Will think about the algo ;)

Comment: Algo/logical error was fixed and mongobulk2.groovy is now running. I hoped that I get an significant performance boost but that's not the case ;(